# Php session is destroying automatically, I need to remove its timeout to never expire

Tags: php, session

I am working on a game site and I need the session to work without timeout, so that I can save games that were last played in my games section of site. There is no login functionality on the site, that's why I am looking for session to be kept alive.

By the way, I have defined 2 settings for session :

```
ini_set( 'session.cookie_lifetime', 84600 );
ini_set( 'session.gc_maxlifetime', 84600 );
```

But still my session is coming empty next day. Could you please help me?

Or is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use client side session in javascript. PHP creates server side session

Comment: I don't know how to do that ? Could you suggest me something like that ?

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
setcookie('user', $user_id, time() + 60*60*24*30, "/");
```

You can make this to happen when some user visit the site and there will be no problem I think.

Comment: I have tried this, it didn't work. I got my session empty in just 2 hours. Even i was refreshing the page and still ..... :(

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS

```
ini_set( 'session.cookie_lifetime', 84600*365 ); // 1 YEAR
ini_set( 'session.gc_maxlifetime', 84600*365 ); // 1 YEAR
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for helping me fix the problem. I got it fixed by adding following code in my common php file.

```
ini_set( 'session.use_only_cookies', "0" ); 
ini_set( 'session.cookie_lifetime', 84600 * 365 ); // 1 YEAR
ini_set( 'session.gc_maxlifetime', 84600 * 365 ); // 1 YEAR
ini_set( 'session.cache_expire', 84600 * 365 ); // 1 YEAR
session_start();
setcookie( session_name(), session_id(), time() + ( 60 * 60 * 24 * 30 * 12 ), "/" );
```

Cheers